# Is it possible to hide related list based on condition?

Tags: apex, configuration

I would like to hide a related list based on condition . For e.g : If the user doesn't have edit access on opportunity, do not display quotes related list or do not show new button, so new related record can;t be created .

Answer (score 3):

You can if you use [Single Related List Component](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rss_related_record_list_single.htm&type=5). You will need to use the [component visibility](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_page_components_visibility.htm&type=5)

[image]

Choose Advanced and Use a [Custom Permission](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_perms_overview.htm&type=5) that is assigned for all users that have the access to edit opportunity